# can I use AWS S3 + Cloudflare to host static JSON files for my mobile app?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare

I've got small static JSON files sitting in an AWS S3 bucket that my (hybrid PhoneGap/Cordova) mobile app needs to read in (not write). I want to use Cloudflare between them. I know there are plenty of articles about static website hosting with this combination but I'm wondering if that's overkill for this? i.e. can I just connect Cloudflare to my S3 bucket without configuring all the static hosting stuff on S3, and if so how?

The JSON files are public and that's fine, I don't need to restrict access to just the app.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you planning to use Cloudfare connected to S3? If its the CDN function, you can use AWS Cloudfront which has better integration support for S3 for static content delivery.

Comment: I need to use Cloudflare because it has better connectivity globally but mostly because it's free (Cloudfront is only free for 12 months and 50 GB)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure static web hosting in S3 to achieve this since it will require an endpoint to forward traffic from Cloudfare.

For more details about the configurations, refer the article on [Static Site Hosting with S3 and CloudFlare](https://wsvincent.com/static-site-hosting-with-s3-and-cloudflare/).